# Enhanced 'for' loop causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, loops

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays psvm = new Arrays();
        psvm.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        Scanner ben = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr = new int[4];
        int[] arrs = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = ben.nextInt();
        }
        check(arr, arrs);
    }

    public void check(int arr[], int arrs[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arrs[i] = arr[i];
        }
        for (int i : arrs) {
            System.out.println(arrs[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The enhanced `for` loop gives `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
for (int i : arrs) {
    System.out.println(arrs[i]);
}
```

While this `for` loop statement works. Why? What's wrong with the code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrs.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arrs[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case, `i` will be assigned to each element in the array - it is **not** an index into the array.

What you want to do is:

```
for(int i : arrs)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

In your code, you're trying to select the integer at the array index referenced by the iteration object.  In other words, your code is equivalent to:

```
for(int idx = 0; idx < arrs.length; idx++)
{
    int i = arrs[idx];
    System.out.println(arrs[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this block of code you wrote:

```
for (int i : arrs) {
   System.out.println(arrs[i]);
}
```

You can put an index variable outside of the loop, then you can use the index to output the values of the array indices. Just ensure to increment when your work is done for that index.

Take a look below:

```
int index = 0;
for (int i : arrs) {
   System.out.println(arrs[index]);
   index++;
}
```